Cracks In Ceiling
I just noticed small cracks in the ceiling of a bedroom. My house is a new build that's about 2.5 years old. The crack spans maybe ~2-3 inches along it's greatest dimension. I don't see any signs of water. Above this ceiling is the attic.
Does anyone have any idea what can cause this?
Picture 1 (Close Up) - https://imgur.com/a/rHkr8DB
Picture 2 (Close up) - https://imgur.com/06iWJ1I
Picture 3 (With Camera Few Feet Away) - https://imgur.com/rYR8bsQ
I'll try to monitor this to see if it gets worse and might also try to look in the attic if it's possible.

It would be nice is you'd [edit] your question to use the built-in image hosting. It will help preserve the life of the question and might help someone else long after you've found your solution.

The pictures show cracking in the paint layer.
This indicates an issue with the paint or contamination on the surface that was painted, such as oils or a substance not compatible with latex paint.
This is a cosmetic issue and not structural.
The fix would be to lightly scrape away any flaking paint. Wipe the area with a damp cloth with a degreaser. Allow to dry. Prime with a latex primer and repaint.

A good prep is 90% of a good paint job.
